# How to join on subquery with rank using predicate in spring data jpa?

Tags: sql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, predicate

I have two tables Project and Deals. From deals to project is many to one relation. That means one project can have multiple deals. Now My requirement is to find all the projects mapped with the most recent deals. That means for each project find all the deals based on the last modified date for that deal and give the project with association with the deal with most recent update date.

I have created one query also.

```
SELECT 
    project0_.PROJECT_ID       
  FROM PROJECT project0_
  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT d.PROJECT_ID,
      (rank() over ( partition BY d.PROJECT_ID order by d.LAST_MODIFIED_TS DESC) ) RNO,
      d.deal_id,
      d.LAST_MODIFIED_TS
    FROM DEALS d
    ) d1
  ON project0_.PROJECT_ID = d1.PROJECT_ID
  WHERE  RNO                        =1;
```

But i am not able to achieve this through Spring data Jpa specification and predicate.